# What is a slot?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When reading about SQL I've come across the term 'slot'.  For example, in a DBCC error message you may get something like this which references slot 0:

Page (1:157), slot 0 in object ID 2121058592, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594038517760, alloc unit ID 72057594042515456 (type "In-row data"). Column "col2" value is out of range for data type "datetime". Update column to a legal value.

I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the physical location but I can't find a definition anywhere which gives its exact meaning.

Any ideas?

Comment: thanks very much for the replies, I wasn't getting anywhere searching the web.  Both links were also very good, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the ordinal corresponding to the record number for a given page.  Slot 0 is the first record on a page.  See [this post](http://sqlfool.com/2009/05/overhead-i-non-unique-clustered-indexes/) by Michelle Ufford for a reference in context.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an illustration. In a data page, the individual elements of the Row offset array are known as slots. Read [this article](http://www.improve.dk/blog/2009/03/26/deciphering-a-sql-server-data-page) for more information.

[image]
<sub>(source: [improve.dk](http://www.improve.dk/images/content/small/deciph-page-structure.jpg))</sub>